# Problem Causing Variables to be Re-evaluated on React Re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm finding a small issue causing `let` instantiated variables to be modified incorrectly within React functional components.

### Expected Behavior

I have a variable (an object) that is modified by follow-on logic like this inside a React functional component:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  let foo = {}
  if (someCondition) {
     delete foo[prop]
  }
  if (someOtherCondition) {
     delete foo[anotherProp]
  }
  ...
  return (<> Object.keys(foo).map(key => {...})</>)
}
```

So basically, I'm trying to use only specific properties on this object based on other conditions, like a specific conditional use of the Component.

The `foo` variable is an object that's returned from a query to a database. Specifically, in the parent Component to `SomeComponent`, I'm running a query that returns information (in the form of an object) about a company. `foo` is one property from that return that is also an object. When the query is complete, the result of the query is passed down into `SomeComponent`, so `foo` is not stateful in `SomeComponent`.

### The Problem

I'm noticing that, when the above Component is brought into the DOM the first time, it works as expected. So, for example, if I bring the Component into the DOM under "circumstance 1", it will work properly. However, if I then bring it into the DOM under another, different circumstance (let's call it "circumstance 2"--a circumstance when the `foo` object should have a different set of `prop`s deleted from it that when rendered under "circumstance 1", `foo` will not be modified correctly.

Specifically, I notice that `foo` will have **both** the properties deleted from it as if it met both `someCondition` and `someOtherCondition`.

If you have any leads on this challenge, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Where and how does foo get its value from?

Comment: Please describe how you get foo variable. You mentioned that you were getting new values from props? In this case, you will need to use `useMemo` to get the new filtered data. e.g.  `const newFoo = useMemo(()=>{ return filterdFoo;}, [props.originalFoo])`

Comment: At a guess, if you're committed to the mutating approach of `delete`, then take a copy of `foo` and mess with that instead. `const localFoo = {...foo}`.

Comment: If you provide real code or reproduce the issue on a sandbox, it would be easier to debug it. As others said, you probably are messing with mutable operations on that object, and you should always use useMemo when doing operations like that one.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis I've updated the question to provide more details around `foo`. Per @Liki and @Cesare, I'm going to work with `useMemo` and see if that helps.